# xnaliveproxy cannot find xlive.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, xna

I know that this is a common problem, but xnaliveproxy cannot find xlive.dll on my computer. This message pops up when I debug my program. The weird thing is that it only popped up after I typed this line of code:

```
 Components.Add(new GamerServicesComponent(this));
```

and if I take that line away again, it debugs the program fine.
I have been told that I should not download the xlive.dll file, but rather re-install the program that needs it, But I cannot find xnaliveproxy uninstall or re-install on my pc.

How would I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded windows xna framework 4.0 refresh. Fixed the problem.